# What is the point of a spied instance

Tags: mockito

I was debugging a test using `spy` and found something very confusing.

```
public class SpyTest {

    @Test
    public void testSpy1(){
        Thing thing = new Thing();
        Thing thingSpy = Mockito.spy(thing);
        thingSpy.modify("bar");
        assertThat(thing.getFoo(), is("bar"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSpy2(){
        Thing thing = new Thing();
        Thing thingSpy = Mockito.spy(thing);
        thingSpy.modify("bar");
        assertThat(thingSpy.getFoo(), is("bar"));
    }

    private static class Thing {
        private String foo = "";

        public void modify(String foo){
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        public String getFoo() {
            return foo;
        }
    }
}
```

I expected spy to defer to the passed instance.

`testSpy1` fails and `testSpy2` succeeds, because I tried to read data from the actual object instead of the spy. So, if spy does not interact with the passed object, why does it accept one and why does it keep it around in the mock settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A spy *makes a shallow copy of the fields* of the passed object. Mocks don't use normal constructors or initializers, so in a normal Mockito mock, all of the fields will stay in their default state (0, null, false, etc). This can make it hard to call real methods on a mock, since many instance methods interact with some of their instance's state, and uninitialized fields are often invalid. By allowing normal construction, and then copying the state, a spy object can behave almost exactly like a normal object—except with the stubbing and verification capabilities Mockito provides.

Though you could use a normal Mockito-created mock and set its fields, this would tend to break encapsulation, and in any case would not make it easy to set private or final fields. With the current spy syntax, you can call the constructor of your choice with the parameters of your choice and set up your class as accurately as possible.

But why not keep the old object and delegate to it? The answer is `this`:

```
class AnotherThing {
  String greet() {
    return "Hello " + getName() + "!";
  }

  String getName() {
    return "World";
  }
}

class AnotherThingTest {
  void testOverrideName() {
    AnotherThing anotherThing = new AnotherThing();
    AnotherThing spyOfAnotherThing = spy(anotherThing);
    doReturn("Dolly").when(spyOfAnotherThing).getName();
    assertEquals("Hello Dolly!", spyOfAnotherThing.greet());  // fails!
  }
}
```

The above seems like a reasonable test, but if Mockito were to delegate to your AnotherThing instance, it would fail: `spyOfAnotherThing` would delegate to `anotherThing`, which would call `getName` (explicitly `this.getName()`) on *itself*, which would return the default "World". In order for partial mocking to work, the value of `this` must be identical between the spy implementation and the original implementation, and this requires a copy.

For this reason, you'll often see `spy(new ClassToSpy())`, where the developer does not keep a reference to the spy's original object. This can help avoid confusion about which instance to interact with, and I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now that I read all of the documentation, it does say that the object is only used for the fields